# ESP32 compile probem

Tags: compiler-errors, wifi, iot, esp32, arduino-ide

I am having trouble with my board esp32. It's said that error compiling for esp32 dev module. Please can you help me? I will paste the error message below:

Arduino: 1.8.16 (Windows Store 1.8.51.0) (Windows 10), Board: "ESP32 Dev Module, Disabled, Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS), 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 921600, None"

In file included from C:\Users\Win10\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DHTLib\dht.h:18:0,

```
             from C:\Users\Win10\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DHTLib\dht.cpp:30:
```

C:\Users\Win10\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DHTLib\dht.cpp: In member function 'int dht::_readSensor(uint8_t, uint8_t)':

C:\Users\Win10\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:106:91: error: cannot convert 'volatile uint32_t* {aka volatile unsigned int*}' to 'volatile uint8_t* {aka volatile unsigned char*}' in initialization

#define portInputRegister(port)     ((volatile uint32_t*)((port)?GPIO_IN1_REG:GPIO_IN_REG))

```
                                                                                       ^
```

C:\Users\Win10\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DHTLib\dht.cpp:116:29: note: in expansion of macro 'portInputRegister'

```
 volatile uint8_t *PIR = portInputRegister(port);

                         ^
```

Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"

Used: C:\Users\Win10\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\libraries\WiFi

Not used: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.51.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\WiFi

exit status 1

Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: did you try `volatile uint32_t *PIR = portInputRegister(port);`?

Comment: you mean to the file dht.cpp ?

Answer (score 0):

The library [DHTlib](https://github.com/RobTillaart/DHTlib) is designed only to work on Arduino AVR CPUs. You're trying to use it on an ESP32, which is a completely different architecture.

You'll either need to rewrite its low level I/O functions to work with the ESP32 - which is a lot more work than just fixing this error - or use a library that's written to support the ESP32.

[DHTLib's author recommends using a different library](https://github.com/RobTillaart/DHTlib/issues/3), [DHTNew](https://github.com/RobTillaart/DHTNew), which compiles correctly on both the ESP8266 and ESP32. It's not 100% software compatible with DHTLib but it's used similarly.